# how can I remove a variable amount of characters from the end of javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, variables, slice

I've been trying to get something like this to work but it just won't:

```
var str = str.slice(0, -"variable");
```

I need to remove a variable amount of characters from the end. thanks!

Comment: Why is the variable name in quotes?

Comment: Please use the snippet tool and show us precisely what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
var str = "Hello, World";
var chars = 7;
var sliced = str.slice(0, -chars);
console.log(sliced);
```

Answer (score 0):

This `-"variable"` is a coercion logic, so basically you're executing something as follow: `str.slice(0, NaN);`

```js
console.log(-"variable"); // js engine is trying to convert to number
```

Just use the variable, you don't need to wrap it with quotes like a string.

```js
var variable = 5;
var str = "EleFromStack".slice(0, -variable);
console.log(str)
```